# How to add values of 2 textboxes and check whether its equal to the third?

Tags: c#, asp.net, customvalidator

I have a form where I've multiple `textboxes` and a `dropdown` menu with it.

I want to calculate and check whether the sum of these `textboxes` is equal to third with each textbox has a `dropdown` menu along with it and the values of that dropdown menu are +1 or -1. For example, I have controls as following:

```
 txt1 with ddl1; txt2 with ddl2; txt3 with ddl3; txt4 with ddl4;
```

I want to check whether:

```
 txt1 * ddl1 = ((txt2 * ddl2) + (txt3 * ddl3) + (txt4 * ddl4))
```

Also, I am using a custom validator and want to check this condition in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you need to change you textbox and ddl value to integer first.

int txt1 = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
            int dd1 = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

```
        int txt2 = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
        int dd2 = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList2.SelectedValue);

        int txt3 = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text);
        int dd3 = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList3.SelectedValue);


        if (txt1 * dd1 == (txt2 * dd2) + (txt3 * dd3))
        {
            //YOur code here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function Total() {
            var sumofall;            
            var FirstText = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
            var SecondText = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
            var ThirdText = document.getElementById('txt3').value;
            var FouthText = document.getElementById('txt4').value;
            var dropdown = document.getElementById("ddl1");
            var dropdown2 = document.getElementById("ddl2");
            var dropdown3 = document.getElementById("ddl3");
            var dropdown4 = document.getElementById("ddl4");
            var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
            var value2 = dropdown2.options[dropdown2.selectedIndex].value;
            var value3 = dropdown3.options[dropdown3.selectedIndex].value;
            var value4 = dropdown4.options[dropdown4.selectedIndex].value;
            var text = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].text;
            var text2 = dropdown2.options[dropdown2.selectedIndex].text;
            var text3 = dropdown3.options[dropdown3.selectedIndex].text;
            var text4 = dropdown4.options[dropdown4.selectedIndex].text;

            if (FirstText == "")
                FirstText = 0;
            if (dropdown == "")
                dropdown = 0;

            var result = parseInt(FirstText) * parseInt(text);
            if (!isNaN(result)) {

            }
            if (SecondText == "")
                SecondText = 0;
            if (dropdown2 == "")
                dropdown2 = 0;

            if (ThirdText == "")
                ThirdText = 0;
            if (dropdown3 == "")
                dropdown3 = 0;

            if (FouthText == "")
                FouthText = 0;
            if (dropdown4 == "")
                dropdown4 = 0;

            var result2 = parseInt(SecondText) * parseInt(text2);
            var result3 = parseInt(ThirdText) * parseInt(text3);
            var result4 = parseInt(FouthText) * parseInt(text4);

            if (!isNaN(result2) && !isNaN(result3) && !isNaN(result4)) {
                sumofall = result2 + result3 + result4;
            }


            if (result == sumofall)
                alert('Something');
            else
                alert('Error..Not Matched');
                return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the server function of the custom validator you can write:

```
int firstValue = 0;
if(int32.TryParse(txt1.Text), out firstValue)
{
    int secondValue = 0;
    if(int32.TryParse(txt2.Text), out secondValue)
    {
         // ...
         // check other value, then
         arg.IsValid = firstValue * Convert.ToInt32(ddl1.SelectedValue) == 
                  (secondValue * Convert.ToInt32(ddl2.SelectedValue)) +
                  (thirdValue * Convert.ToInt32(ddl3.SelectedValue)) +
                  (fourthValue * Convert.ToInt32(ddl4.SelectedValue));

    }
    else
         lblEsito = "Il valore nel secondo TextBox non è un intero";
}
else
    lblEsito = "Il valore nel primo TextBox non è un intero";
```

I have supposed values of dropdownlists are integer and any "Select" with value "0" or "" is present in the dropdownlist controls.
Next time you have to post some code.